# Add a watermark to a external image and then store it

Tags: php

I need a way to add a watermark to the center of the external image ( from another domain ) and then store it in my filesystem.

This is my code:

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('centerbutton.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg( 'https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg' );

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

$imgx = imagesx($im);
$imgy = imagesy($im);
$centerX=round($imgx/2);
$centerY=round($imgy/2);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, $centerX, $centerY, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
imagejpeg($im,"img/newimage.jpg");
imagedestroy($im);
```

The problem is that it store nothing.
Why ?

Comment: Got error reporting enabled? Checked the return value of `imagejpeg()`? Does your script have write permission for the `img` directory?

Comment: worked fine for me, check for permissions and path.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone In phpinfo I see: allow_url_fopen On On

Comment: With error reporting enabled I get this: "imagejpeg(img/newimage.jpg): failed to open stream"

Comment: `$centerX` and `$centerY` do not account for the size of the watermark. You need to subtract half the width and half the height, respectively.

Comment: @PHPglue yes you right, thanks :)

Comment: Ok the problem was the permissions of the folder. Thank you guys :D